# Running a Perl script and entering commands into it from Python

Tags: python, perl, python-2.7

I'm a week into learning Python and am trying to write a piece of code that allows me to run a text-based Perl script in LXTerminal automatically.  I have a couple of questions regarding some specifics.

I need my code to start the Perl script with a user-inputted environment file, enter a few specific settings into the Perl script, and then read in many .txt files, one at a time, into the Perl script.  It also needs to restart the process for every single .txt file and capture each individual output (it would help if every output could be written to a single .csv file).

To call the Perl script, I'm starting with the following:

```
alphamelts="/home/melts/Desktop/alphamelts"
pipe=subprocess.Popen(["perl", "/home/Desktop/melts/alphaMELTS", "run_alphamelts.command -f %s"]) % raw_input("Enter an environment  file:"), stdout=PIPE
```

Assuming that's correct, I now need it to read in a .txt file, enter number-based commands, have my code wait for the Perl script to finish its calculations, and I need it to write the output to a .csv file.  If it helps, the Perl script I'm running automatically generates a space delimited file containing the results of its calculations once the program exists, but it would be super helpful if only a few of its outputs were written onto a single seperate .csv file for each .txt file processed.

No idea where to go from here but I absolutely have to get this working.  Sorry for the complexity.

Thank you!

Comment: When you can predict the input expected by the program, i.e. if you know beforehand which answers in which order the user would have to enter when the external program prompts for it, then you can use the `communicate()` method of `pipe`.

Comment: Thank you  I'll check that out.

Comment: If the Perl script is interactive, you may want to check out [pexpect](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pexpect)

Answer (score -1):

you can do some really cool stuff in ipython. Check out [this notebook](https://github.com/nagordon/technotes/blob/master/ipython-perl-octave.ipynb) for some specific examples. As far as waiting for a subprocess to finish, I think you need to put a `pause` in your script. Also, for data handling and export to csv and excel, I'd recommend [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/)
Just something to get you started.

Comment: The question as far as I understand it was how to communicate with a running perl program which asks for user input.

Comment: Yes that is part of my question, Blackjack.